# How do I fix the SQL Server error "The multi-part identifier 'X.Y' could not be bound"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been trying to develop a tax calculator. I'm trying to do the computation in SQL, but am not good with it, so please bear with me.

```
IF (12500 > WTAX_DAILY.HI_LIMIT)
(
    SELECT (HI_LIMIT) "DEDUCTION"
    FROM
    (
        SELECT HI_LIMIT, EXEMPTION  FROM WTAX_MONTHLY WHERE LO_LIMIT <= 12500 AND HI_LIMIT >= 12500
    )T
)
ELSE IF (12500 < WTAX_DAILY.HI_LIMIT)
(
    SELECT (LO_LIMIT) "DEDUCTION"
    FROM
    (
        SELECT LO_LIMIT, EXEMPTION  FROM WTAX_MONTHLY WHERE LO_LIMIT <= 12500 AND HI_LIMIT >= 12500
    )T
)
```

Here's the error I got:

```
[Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "WTAX_DAILY.HI_LIMIT" could not be bound.
42000 - [SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "WTAX_DAILY.HI_LIMIT" could not be bound.
```

Comment: Remove `THEN` from `IF` statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: (Remove `THEN` FROM `IF` statement)

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM WTAX_MONTHLY WHERE HI_LIMIT < 12500)
    SELECT (HI_LIMIT) "DEDUCTION"
    FROM
        (SELECT HI_LIMIT, EXEMPTION
         FROM   WTAX_MONTHLY
         WHERE  LO_LIMIT <= 12500 AND HI_LIMIT >= 12500
        ) AS T
ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM WTAX_MONTHLY WHERE HI_LIMIT > 12500) 
    SELECT (LO_LIMIT) "DEDUCTION"
    FROM
        (SELECT LO_LIMIT, EXEMPTION 
         FROM   WTAX_MONTHLY
         WHERE  LO_LIMIT <= 12500 AND HI_LIMIT >= 12500
        ) AS T
```

**Updated**

```
SELECT CASE 
           WHEN HI_LIMIT > 12500 THEN 
                HI_LIMIT 
           ELSE LO_LIMIT 
       END AS DEDUCTION
FROM   WTAX_MONTHLY
```

Comment: `[Err] 42S22 - [SQL Server]Invalid column name 'HI_LIMIT'.
42S22 - [SQL Server]Invalid column name 'HI_LIMIT'.`tHIS IS THE ERROR WITH REGARDS THE CODE YOU GAVE

Comment: Is the `HI_LIMIT` in `IF` is parameter or variable?

Comment: Variable sir. It's a column name. ;D

Comment: Please check your sub query... Both are having same condition only Column name different in SELECT list. I think you need to change the condition

Comment: It works but I need to have select hi limit if 12500 is smaller then hi limit, thus it needs to select low limit instead. I will only select hi limit if 12500 is higher than hi limit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59258/discussion-between-jesuraja-and-dodgeball).

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error it is because you are trying to use Column Names inside your IF..ELSE statements, you cannot do this... IF..ELSE can only compare scalar values. Hard coded or Variables but only single value. You will need to use a CASE statement inside your Select statement. Se below:

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN 12500 > HI_LIMIT 
             THEN HI_LIMIT 
            ELSE LO_LIMIT END AS  [DEDUCTION]
FROM  WTAX_MONTHLY
--WHERE LO_LIMIT <= 12500 
--  AND HI_LIMIT >= 12500
```

Answer (score 0):

With regards to Jesuraja, I just modified his answer a bit and this is what shows up. Now it runs perfectly. Thanks Jesu

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM WTAX_MONTHLY WHERE HI_LIMIT < 15850)
SELECT (LO_LIMIT) "DEDUCTION"
FROM
    (SELECT LO_LIMIT, EXEMPTION
     FROM   WTAX_MONTHLY
     WHERE  LO_LIMIT <= 15850 AND HI_LIMIT >= 15850
    ) AS T
ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM WTAX_MONTHLY WHERE HI_LIMIT > 15850) 
SELECT (HI_LIMIT) "DEDUCTION"
FROM
    (SELECT HI_LIMIT, EXEMPTION 
     FROM   WTAX_MONTHLY
     WHERE  LO_LIMIT <= 15850 AND HI_LIMIT >= 15850
    ) AS T
```